# How to get reference of application project into library project?

Tags: android, reference, android-library

I am going to make application with library project. My application project referred a library project.

When we build the dependent application project, library projects are compiled and merged with the application project, so application project has all the resources which library have.

But my requirement is slightly reverse from above. I want application project resources reference into library project. I want to access R.java of application project into reference library project.

Is there any way to get reference of dependent project into library project?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way as far as I know. And it is also not the idea of "Lib" projects that they depend on a App Project. It is only made for a vice versa dependency.